# Unable to open modal pop up window using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I could not open the modal pop up window each time click on button using Angular.js.

Here is my code:

```
<button tybe="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" style="padding: 0px 4px;" ng-click="getPriceDetails();">Get Price Details</button>
<modal title="Tariff Information" class="viewpricemodal" visible="priceDetails">
  <h4 class="text-center">Total Fare ₹76</h4>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Basic Fare</td>
          <td align="right">₹70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rate per km</td>
          <td align="right">₹2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ride time charge per min</td>
          <td align="right">₹1</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="text-center">Total fare may change if route or destination changes or if any ride takes longer due to traffic or other factors.
Total fare doesn't include waiting fee.</p>
</modal>

$scope.getPriceDetails=function(){
        //$scope.priceDetails=false;
        //console.log('price',$scope.priceDetails);
        $scope.priceDetails = !$scope.priceDetails;
    }
```

Here I can open popup modal after 2 times click on that button. I need each time click on that button that modal should open. I am using `angular.js ui-bootstrap` for the modal pop up window.

Comment: Please specify the angular Version; also is the `priceDetails` variable initialized?

Comment: You are displaying Modal on the basis of priceDetails variable, every time you click button priceDetails will be first set to False and then to true on second time.

Comment: @AmitabhDas: I am using angular.js version 1.6.x.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: I am commented those lines. without those lines also same issue.

Comment: What is the initial value of $scope.priceDetails;

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: First time click its `undefined` and pop up is open then closed the modal when again click on button its not opening. means rather than first time each 2 times click on button its opening the modal.

Comment: For the second time it will true when clicked will become false on third time it will be again set to true. So every time you close the modal you should reinitialize `$scope.priceDetails` to false

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: Then how to handle it here. I also checked setting each time false but same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195668/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-satya).

Comment: Also what version of Angular ui bootstrap are you using?